# How to edit a specific column with unix command?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I would like to edit the fourth column for the IP number as in the example below:

**Input file:**

```
$ cat file
server01                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.3[12345]<OS>server01</OS>
server02                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.2[12345]<OS>server02</OS>
server03                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.3[12345]<OS>server03</OS>
```

**Desired output:**

```
server01                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
server02                SW  Y   10.0.0.2
server03                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've shown us 2 different versions of output but so far no input. If you [edit] your question to include the input that would produce that output then we could help you write a script to perform that transformation. Without the input, we'd just be guessing wildly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to put the input command, I already edited, thank you.

Comment: You still haven't provided the input. You've posted "Output" and "Desired output" but no "Input". Not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: @IsaqueBenatti: Since you added `cat file` where you had **Output** I am assuming that is actually your input file. I edited appropriately. Roll back if I assumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like Perl a bunch as my command line regex tool, present on nearly all Unix shells.

This will do fine for most cases

```
command | perl -pe 's/[^\s]+?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[^\s]+/$1/g'
```

It works by matching an ip with junk before and after, IP = `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`, the junk before/after (non-whitespace characters) `[^\s]+` (`?` = greedy) and replacing it by the matches IP address

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ cat file
server01                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.3[12345]<OS>server01</OS>
server02                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.2[12345]<OS>server02</OS>
server03                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.3[12345]<OS>server03</OS>
```

Then, the following command will give you the desired output:

```
$ sed 's/as.fdsas:#//g' file | sed 's/\[12345\]//g' | sed 's/\<OS\>server..\<\/OS\>//g'
server01                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
server02                SW  Y   10.0.0.2
server03                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
```

Note:
It's not very general, so if you have variation in what the output looks like, then it'll need to be modified.  Also, if you want this stored in a file, then you can add `| cat > filename` to it, like so:

```
$ sed 's/as.fdsas:#//g' file | sed 's/\[12345\]//g' | sed 's/\<OS\>server..\<\/OS\>//g' | cat > f1

$ cat f1
server01                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
server02                SW  Y   10.0.0.2
server03                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
server01                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.3[12345]<OS>server01</OS>
server02                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.2[12345]<OS>server02</OS>
server03                SW  Y   as.fdsas:#10.0.0.3[12345]<OS>server03</OS>
```

You can get your fields with awk:

```
awk '{split($4,arr,/[#\[]/); printf "%-23s %s  %s   %s\n" ,$1, $2, $3, arr[2]}' file
server01                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
server02                SW  Y   10.0.0.2
server03                SW  Y   10.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed can be useful here:

```
sed 's/[\.a-z]*:#\([0-9\.]*\)\[.*/\1/'
```